# VBA Internet Explorer Automation: getting automation error on iframe

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, iframe

I am currently automating a website to pull some data. Before, my code is working fine and i was able to pull the needed data properly. But for some reasons when I test my code again I am getting an "automation error" on the part where I set the my object variable to get the "iframe".

```
Set html = IE.Document
' This is the line where i get my "automation error"
Set htmlelements = html.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

htmlelement.Click

Set htmlelements2 = html.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("tr")

For Each htmlelement2 In htmlelements2
    Data = htmlelement2.Children(2).textContent
end for
```

is it possible for the website to prevent vbscript from pulling their own data. I can't share the website link because it is confidential. Needed desperate help for this one, hoping someone could help me.

Comment: Have you declared `htmlelements` as an object?

Comment: yes i did, i have declaration in all my variable. What i post here is just a part of my code.

Comment: Is there an URL you can share? And can you show some of the relevant html please as well as more of your code. Also, give the full error message please along with any error number.

Comment: @ashleedawg Kinda snowed down with work but did just spot this rather tardily. It's a SQL day at work.......

Comment: [this is the url](http://www.anterior.banxico.org.mx/portal-mercado-cambiario/foreign-exchange-markets--exc.html)  what i need to do is click the "More information" and get the rates. Also the error that i'm getting is "automation error or Error 404"

Comment: @JohnLouieGonzales As QHarr mentioned, if you could provide the URL or some of the HTML that would help a lot... the entire code (redacted if needed) would be great

Comment: I already provided the URL... for the code i think that is all i need to provide... that is the code that i use to click a label and pull out a data. the rest of my code is to create the IE and visit the URL

Comment: We can't see if you are using InternetExplorer or InternetExplorerMedium in the code above for examle. Have you tried with both?

Comment: And is the page always so slow loading for you? It may be that it times out.

Comment: i use internet explorer references in vba... for the loading i dont know why it is slow